# Array fundamental

Tags: java

I have one array size of 11 with String, i add some item in it.

### Decalration::

```
 String arr_sound[] = new String[11];
```

### Initialization::

```
arr_sound[0] = "bike_route.mp3";
    arr_sound[1] = "closed.mp3";
    arr_sound[2] = "exit.mp3";
    arr_sound[3] = "no_parking.mp3";  
                 ....
                 ....
    arr_sound[11] = "touch_and_show.mp3";
```

**Problem** if i am initialize with ***`arr_sound[01] = "closed.mp3"`*** give error.any solution ?
Thanks

Comment: "give error"?? **Which** error? Tell us the **exact** error message you get.

Comment: Also: is there a reason you don't just define it as `String[] arr_sound = { "bike_route.mp3", "closed.mp3", ..., "touch_and_show.mp3" };`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
arr_sound[11] = "touch_and_show.mp3";
```

Should throw an ArrayOutOfBoundException.

Your array can contain 11 Items as defined.
The first goes into `arr_sound[0]`
And the 11th and last into `arr_sound[10]`.

`arr_sound[11]` would be the 12th item.

Comment: "Your array cant contain 11 Items as defined." is incorrect; it can contain 11 elements and will throw an exception when 12th item's insertion is attempted. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should know that in java numbers that start with `0` - are octal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use code like this:

```
arr_sound[01] = ...
```

or

```
arr_sound[11] = ...
```

because the index is an int and has to be from `0` to `10`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr_sound[11] = "touch_and_show.mp3";
```

This will not work if your array has only 11 elements. You need to create an array with 12 elements:

```
new String[12];
```

Comment: Because the index of the array in Java is zero based. For a 12 element array you have the indexes 0 .. 11.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you initializing with **`O1`**?

The correct thing should start from 0 because that's the first default index for java, unless you set it otherwise.

**`arr_sound[0] arr_sound[1] . . . arr_sound[10]`**

Values that start with 0 are likely octal.